# Swipe-based navigation

Tags: ios

I'm hoping to hear any thoughts people have on how to architecture a swipe based menu/selection.

Basically, what I want to do is create a portion of the screen that can be swiped (left or right) to select between one of say five images.  For example, a server would deliver 5 images that reflect "headlines" or "stories" that when a user clicks on the individual image, it would send the user to a new view that can display the related content.  The user could switch between the images by swiping either left or right.

I would want to lazily update the images and supplemental information for the forward and backward image to minimize delay for the user.

I can imagine how I would set up the data to support the swiping action and then send data to the selected view so that it can be displayed.

What I'm curious about is what people think the best method of designing the actual swipable menu would be.  I know when apps provide, for example, swipable images there is discussion about using a UIScrollView and updating the images that way.  Or, I could use UIViewController containment to simply create five or so separate views that are swapped between based on the user swipe.  Or, there may be a much better way of doing this.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I just used a variation of Apple's pageControl example.  Seems to do the trick.